# how to get data from website through URL

Tags: javascript, php, objective-c, web-scraping

i am trying to create an ios appplication which can data from website and can show me in an application.Is there any way though which i can get data from a website and show that data into my ios application?? please guide if something you have for me

Comment: yes with JSon and $_post

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and no one will do all the work for you. Please show us some code you messed up with and we'll be glad to help improve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most sites expect a GET request.

Open a network connection to the server on port 80. Send the text "GET /rest_of_url"  and read the text that comes back. It is up to you what you do with the response.

Try it with a simple raw terminal like putty to see how the server responds before going too deep coding.

Secure sites with https will take more work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you can get datas from your URL with the following code

```
-(void) getDataWithCompletionHandler:(void(^ _Nonnull)(void))completion{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
[self setRequestProperty:request];
[[[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:Nil] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable retour, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    [self handleResponse:completion withDatas:data andTheHTTPResponse:retour];
}] resume];
```

}